# Pandas filter maximum groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, minimax

I have Pandas df:

```
family  age fruits
------------------
Brown   12  7
Brown   33  5
Yellow  28  3
Yellow  11  9
```

I want to get ages with next conditions:

1. Group by family;
2. Having maximum of fruits

So result df will be:

```
family  age
-----------
Brown   12
Yellow  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do:

```
(df.sort_values(['family','fruits'], ascending=[True,False])
   .drop_duplicates('family')
)
```

Output:

```
   family  age  fruits
0   Brown   12       7
3  Yellow   11       9
```

Or with `groupby().idxmax()`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('family').fruits.idxmax(), ['family','age'] ]
```

Output:

```
   family  age
0   Brown   12
3  Yellow   11
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `head` after `sort_values`

```
df.sort_values(
    ['family','fruits'], ascending=[True,False])
        .groupby('family').head(1)
```